# Export internally stored video to the android gallery

Tags: android, outputstream, android-gallery, fileoutputstream

I currently have an app that can import videos from the android gallery, make a copy of them, and then delete the old file if the user wants to.

Now, I need the user to be able to reverse that action and transfer the video from the app's internal storage to the android gallery.

Here's what i've tried so far :

```
        //storage/emulated/0/Pictures -- getPath() of line below
        File androidVidGalleryPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File hiddenVideo = new File("/data/data/mypackagename/app_vidDir/vid_10.mp4");
        File exportedVid = new File(androidVidGalleryPath.getPath()+"/DesiredAlbumName/"+"DesiredVideoName");

        try {
            FileOutputStream newFile = new FileOutputStream (exportedVid);
            FileInputStream oldFile = new FileInputStream (hiddenVideo);

            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; //this will only read 1KB of data, definitely not enough for an entire video.
            oldFile.read(buf);
            newFile.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
            newFile.flush();
            newFile.close();
            oldFile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(exportedVid.getPath());
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

For some reason, nothing happens, other than the warning toast that the try catch caused an IOException.

I'm not sure what's going on, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a while loop, when you write the file.:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[1024]; //this will only read 1KB of data, definitely not enough for an entire video.
oldFile.read(buf);
newFile.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
```

After you transfer the video, do this (from here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskGallery)

```
private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Comment: I've added that, the issue remains unresolved. It seems as if the file is never truly read. I'm using 2 examples for this, one of the files is 10+ minutes, the other 20 or so seconds. When saving the 10 minute file in a similar manner, it takes upwards to 45 seconds to do so, when i try to export the file, it takes less than a second. Leading me to believe that the file is never truly read.

Comment: do you have the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Comment: Why don't you use File.renameTo() and (check the return value to make sure it goes through) http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: Yes, i have that permission. Let me see what i can do with .renameTo real quick.

Comment: I've updated my question to incorporate the solutions you've proposed, unfortunately, i'm stilling having an issue as the large file is still moved in under one second and doesn't appear in the android gallery.

Comment: did you see the comment i put? If you make your bufferSize 1024, that is only 1 kilobyte that get's read. That's why it's so fast. It's not appearing in the gallery because we're not reading the whole file, so it's an invalid media file.

Comment: Another thing do DesiredAlbumName/ and DesiredVideoName/ folders exist. If not you have to use mkdirs() to make them. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs()

Comment: Instead of 1024 there, what should i put?

Comment: You have to make it bigger than the size of your file. 1024*1024 is 1 MB. So if your file is under 10 MB 10*1024*1024 would work.

Comment: Even with setting the size up to 100*1024*1024 for a 20 second video, it still only takes under a second and the file in the gallery is "Unable to be played". There must be an issue else where about the video file, i'm going to look into it some more.

Comment: Turns out that  the try catch was causing an error due to somehow the file became a directory, so i reinstalled the app, and changed mkdirs() to exportedVid.createNewFile(); . This solved the issue, thanks for your assistance!